# Printing option disabled for "Print to the file"

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I'm trying to send and print any file with code from [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322091) link. But the issue is I'm not able to enable the printer option to page selection range from printer setting dialog. Now after some digging on internet I found some way to do it using below code:

```
PrintDialog.UserPageRangeEnabled()
PrintDialog.ShowDialog()
```

But it seems to be WPF code and not available with normal winform c# application, though I'm using .NET 4.5 framework.

Any clues how to do the same without using WPF?

[image: Print dialog with disabled page selection]

Comment: Where is *your* code? Besides, the link you posted is a support article for sending raw data to the printer, *not* about configuring the print dialog. Did you check the documentation for WinForm's classes, ie PrintDocument, PrintDialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `System.Windows.Forms` namespace there is `PrintDialog` that has Properties:

- AllowCurrentPage
- AllowSelection
- AllowSomePages

Why not use them instead?
Please look at MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.aspx

Edit:
I've found that some people mention usage of:
`PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.SomePages`
would also be neeeded. But it also depends how your code looks like and that is not provided at the moment.